# On what basis are aspects of the environment kept upon a call to execve()?

Tags: c, linux, process, exec

I know that `exec` should replace the entire process image, but I also know that some things like file descriptors are preserved upon a call to one of the `exec`-family functions.

On what basis are aspects of the environment kept upon a call to `execve()`?

Comment: Have you read the man page for `execve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `execve(3)`:

> All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the
>   following:
>
> - The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset
>     to the default (signal(7)).
> - Any alternate signal stack is not preserved (sigaltstack(2)).
> - Memory mappings are not preserved (mmap(2)).
> - Attached System V shared memory segments are detached
>     (shmat(2)).
> - POSIX shared memory regions are unmapped (shm_open(3)).
> - Open POSIX message queue descriptors are closed
>     (mq_overview(7)).
> - Any open POSIX named semaphores are closed (sem_overview(7)).
> - POSIX timers are not preserved (timer_create(2)).
> - Any open directory streams are closed (opendir(3)).
> - Memory locks are not preserved (mlock(2), mlockall(2)).
> - Exit handlers are not preserved (atexit(3), on_exit(3)).
> - The floating-point environment is reset to the default (see
>     fenv(3)).

POSIX also mandates this (although negated):

> The new process shall inherit at least the following attributes from
>   the calling process image:
>
> - Nice value (see nice())
> - semadj values (see semop())
> - Process ID
> - Parent process ID
> - Process group ID
> - Session membership
> - Real user ID
> - Real group ID
> - Supplementary group IDs
> - Time left until an alarm clock signal (see alarm())
> - Current working directory
> - Root directory
> - File mode creation mask (see umask())
> - File size limit (see getrlimit() and setrlimit())
> - Process signal mask (see pthread_sigmask())
> - Pending signal (see sigpending())
> - tms_utime, tms_stime, tms_cutime, and tms_cstime (see times())
> - Resource limits
> - Controlling terminal
> - Interval timers
>
> The initial thread of the new process shall inherit at least the
>   following attributes from the calling thread:
>
> - Signal mask (see sigprocmask() and pthread_sigmask())
> - Pending signals (see sigpending())
>
> All other process attributes defined in this volume of POSIX.1-2017
>   shall be inherited in the new process image from the old process
>   image. All other thread attributes defined in this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2017 shall be inherited in the initial thread in the new
>   process image from the calling thread in the old process image. The
>   inheritance of process or thread attributes not defined by this volume
>   of POSIX.1-2017 is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the documentation of execve (I only read that of the exec family ). Can I generalize and say that all the PCB data is preserved upon the execve?

Comment: @HusseinHijazi Read this again: *"All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the following"*